# Bug in /review, shows me deleted answer for review.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I just had a case where the review system for first posts [showed me an answer](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/52767) for review that was already deleted by a mod 23h ago (originally [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/472926/privileges-for-resetting-password-changing-password-unlocking-account-and-rea/473137#473137) ). It also was listed with 0 votes, while it racked up -5 before being deleted.  I think that's strange and shouldn't happen, but is the actually expected behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah nonsense, this was the new "Are you paying attention" crap, which now thinks I didn't pay attention as I clicked "no action needed". There *was* no action needed, Ian dealt with it already :)

This was the second such test today.

I'll leave this question for reference...

Comment: Really? Reviewers are now tested for sanity? So >90% are going to lose their review privileges soon?

Comment: @syneticon-dj It's relative sanity, you're fine. Now if you'll excuse me [the tequila weasel](http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=474) and I are discussing the relative merits of deleting ALL the things...

Comment: @syneticon-dj  Well, on SO, yeah.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: and on SF/SU too.

Comment: @Iain Are our reviewers really of SO-level quality?  I know it banned a lot of SO reviewers who were blatantly badge-whoring, but I'm not sure the community here will be impacted to the same degree.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I don't think we will either but the automagic revocation of review privileges has been enabled on SF and SU now too.

Comment: @Iain (or voretaq7): Is this happening for everyone or should I be in any way concerned about my reviewing? I have no reason to believe I should be concerned, but one never knows...

Comment: Sven, I believe everyone who uses certain /review queues is subject to 'testing'.

Comment: I'm too lazy to search for it now, there have been multiple questions about this on meta.SO and I _think_ it's been admitted that the testing of reviewers needs to be adjusted to account for this case - where the answer has been dealt with (deleted) so the reviewer shouldn't fail the test when they pick "no action needed."